# Reduce space between title and first section in a modified smfart

Tags: spacing, titles

I am looking for a hack to reduce the space between the line (that appears after the title) and the title of the first section. At the moment, my code modifies smfart somewhat atrociously as follows:

```
\documentclass{smfart}
\usepackage{smfthm, xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\medskip
 {\abstractfont\smf@journalhead\par}\vfil
\begin{center}
 \def\baselinestretch{1.2}\large\vfil
}{\begin{center} \large \vspace{0.2cm}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
{\vfil
\ifx\@empty\smfbyname\else
     {\smfbyfont\smfbyname\ifsmf@byauthor\par\vfil\else\ \fi}%
\fi
   {\edef\smfandname{{\noexpand\normalfont \smfandname}}
    \andify\authors\authors\par}
 \vfil
}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\title{\S 2. Sch\'emas et morphismes de sch\'emas}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Definition of Schemes}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important are only the two lines maked with `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`

```
\documentclass{smfart}
\usepackage{smfthm}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{copyright}
    \begingroup
    \uppercasenonmath\shorttitle
    \ifx\@empty\shortauthors \let\shortauthors\shorttitle
    \else \uppercasenonmath\shortauthors \andify\shortauthors \fi
    \toks@\@xp{\shortauthors}\@temptokena\@xp{\shorttitle}%
    \edef\@tempa{\@nx\markboth{\the\toks@}{\the\@temptokena}}\@tempa
    \topskip\z@skip
    \vtop to 20 mm{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \parindent=0pt
        \hrule
        \medskip
        {\abstractfont\smf@journalhead\par}\vfil
        \begin{center}
            \def\baselinestretch{1.2}\large\vfil
            {\bfseries\smf@boldmath\MakeUppercase\@title\par}
            \vfil
            \ifx\@empty\smfbyname\else
            {\smfbyfont\smfbyname\ifsmf@byauthor\par\vfil\else\ \fi}%
            \fi
            {\edef\smfandname{{\noexpand\normalfont \smfandname}}
                \andify\authors\authors\par}
            \vfil \vrule height .4pt width .3\textwidth \vfil
        \end{center}}
        \@maketitlehook
        \par\bigskip
        \ifx\@empty\@dedicatory\else\@setdedicatory\medskip\fi
        \@setabstract\par\smallskip\@setaltabstract\par
        \vspace{\normalbaselineskip}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \endgroup}
\makeatother
\title{\S 2. Sch\'emas et morphismes de sch\'emas}

\begin{document}
        \maketitle
        \section{Definition of Schemes}
        \section{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want only reduce the space after the title, then you need only a `\vspace{- ...}`:

```
\documentclass{smfart}
\usepackage{smfthm}
\title{\S 2. Sch\'emas et morphismes de sch\'emas}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \vspace*{-1.5cm}    
    \section{Definition of Schemes}
    \section{foo}
\end{document}
```

If the abstract should be directly after the tile use:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{copyright}
  \begingroup
  \uppercasenonmath\shorttitle
    \ifx\@empty\shortauthors \let\shortauthors\shorttitle
    \else \uppercasenonmath\shortauthors \andify\shortauthors \fi
    \toks@\@xp{\shortauthors}\@temptokena\@xp{\shorttitle}%
    \edef\@tempa{\@nx\markboth{\the\toks@}{\the\@temptokena}}\@tempa
    \topskip\z@skip
    \vtop to 55 mm{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \parindent=0pt
        \hrule
        \medskip
        {\abstractfont\smf@journalhead\par}\vfil
        \begin{center}
            \def\baselinestretch{1.2}\large\vfil
            {\bfseries\smf@boldmath\MakeUppercase\@title\par}
            \vfil
            \ifx\@empty\smfbyname\else
            {\smfbyfont\smfbyname\ifsmf@byauthor\par\vfil\else\ \fi}%
            \fi
            {\edef\smfandname{{\noexpand\normalfont \smfandname}}
                \andify\authors\authors\par}
            {\bigskip\@setabstract\par\smallskip\@setaltabstract\par}
            \vfil \vrule height .4pt width .3\textwidth \vfil
        \end{center}}
        \@maketitlehook
        \par\bigskip
        \ifx\@empty\@dedicatory\else\@setdedicatory\medskip\fi
        \vspace{\normalbaselineskip}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Sheesh! It looks like I just need the `\vspace`. It has been a long time since I ever played around with these things. :( Thanks. Actually, thanks for pointing out those two lines. It is better to use the `normalbaselineskip` as you did because then the abstract should I need it is also placed properly. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Herbert: Actually, the abstract should I like to use one does not get placed. I am unable to unravel how the abstract placement is handled. Any pointers about that would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `\begin{abstract}  your text here \end{abstract}` just after the `\title` definition.

Comment: By placement, I meant in the actual pdf document. Actually, I did figure this part out (this is similar to amsart indeed). Sorry for not being explicit. After the space modifications, what happens now is the abstract goes in some fixed place in the pdf rendition...

Comment: yes, that is what the `smfart`  does by default. The `abtract` ts part of the `maketitle` command

Comment: I guess you know what my next question is ;) Is there a way to make this abstract go right after the title?

Comment: see edited answer. However, it makes nosense to use a special class and then redefine the deafult setting of that special class.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for this! There are other features of this class I like which is why I want to keep this! Sorry!